# Avoiding a quartz shedule miss

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I am using quartz.net and it's great. But what happens if my server is down and I miss an event (I am using a database to store quartz events)? I want to make sure events run, even if they are a week late, but I don't see how this is configured?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic175.html) I've dug up, you can control this through MisfireInstruction.CronTrigger, and setting it to FireOnceNow - this will ensure the task is run once immediately.

Hope that puts you on the right path.